# Compile brscan3 on Raspberry Pi (brother scanner)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, compile, scanner, arm

I am trying to compile `brscan3` (Brother software for scanner) from source file on my Raspberry Pi (arm architecture).

I tried `./configure` but I obtain this error:

```
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in
```

I think I don't use the right compilation command but the source archive contains no `README` or `INSTALL` file.

Link to the source: http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=fr&lang=fr&prod=dcp195c_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006821_000&flang=4&type3=577

Scanner: Brother DCP-195C

Comment: A link to the source code would be useful.

Comment: Yes!! I edited my post.

Comment: Yeah, that truly looks like they're shipping it broken... And other posts on the Internet suggests the same.

Comment: Looks like the source link no longer exists, and couldn't find an archived copy.